# Include gulp minified files in build output

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, gulp-concat

I have been using Gulp to minify and concat my scripts files and complie my SASS files to css. 
We are hosting our files on Visual Studio Team Services and Im trying to use the new Visual studio 2015 build system.
Everything works fine and I'm able to call my gulp task and its runs with no issues. 
The problem is because the files created are not part of the project, they are not included in my deployment package.
I was wondering if anyone else had same problem and found the way to include these files. 
Thansk.

Comment: Have you tried the **Copy and Publish Build Artifacts** task?

Answer (score 2):

You can add following section to your project file to include the extra files:

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="<<<ExtraFilesToInclude>>>" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Refer to this article for details: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes this does. I've implemented it. Was a bit of an issue to test on a server that requires a password though as I was unable to do a preview since doing a preview does not prompt for a password like a publish does.

Comment: Note that for the field <<<ExtraFilesToInclude>>> you should replace it with a pattern such as Include="**/tempFiles/**" or Include="../tempFiles/" etc.